# A stamp kingdom rebus

Tags: rebus, history, tribond

> You may discover three members of which kingdom from the stamps?

[image: A1]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do we need to find 1 kingdom that fits the 3 stamps, or 1 kingdom per stamp?

Comment: Each stamp gives 1 word (same number of letters in each case) and each these 3 words is a  member of the same kingdom.

Comment: @tom What do you mean by same numer of letters?

Comment: @North, Each image produces a word. All three words have equal length - this helps to constrict the individual answers so perhaps I should've included this in the question. (Letters have nothing to go with envelopes if that was a thought.)

Comment: The third rebus question is the least well clued. It just uses the person's name and then is a play on a close reputed relative (without including an  "'s"). The rebus cops may send a car to arrest me.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This might not be the right approach, but here's a possible interpretation of the first two:

> First Stamp
>  Six=VI, P, Queen=ER (Elizabeth Regina=Queen Elizabeth): VIPER (snake)
>  Second Stamp
>  10=TEN, Helvetica=CH ([ISO Country code for Switzerland](http://www.nationsonline.org/oneworld/country_code_list.htm)): TENCH (fish)

Haven't found something similar for the third stamp yet. But these seem more rebus-y to me...

Anyway, as others have found this makes the kingdom the

> Animal kingdom

Here's a guess for the third stamp (not super happy with it):

> 101 (squinting at the two vertical borders and the round one in the middle)=CI; Hermes=VET: CIVET.

Here's a second guess for the third stamp that I have a feeling is right in the sense that it's a Dad joke/bad wordplay.

> Hermes = Pan Dad. But's it is only his head, so it is PANDA...

Comment: Perfect first two and I will check this answer. (The third rebus is not as black and white and I may get fried for the relatively short cluing.)

Comment: Why does queen = er and Helvetica = ch?

Comment: @Bishop, well it's quite simple really. OK, no it isn't. At all. That particular queen happens to be called "Elizabeth II" and her [Royal Cypher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_cypher) looks like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_cypher#/media/File:Royal_Cypher_of_Queen_Elizabeth_II.svg). If you really squint your eyes, you can ignore the two letters in the middle and get "ER". Helvetia (notice the lack of "c") is a country in Europe, better known as Switzerland, and its country code is "ch".

Comment: @Bishop Sorry. Cryptic crossword enthusiasts forget how obtuse some of these shortcuts are. I've tried to spell it out.

Comment: Third one, country code is rot13(RY), so maybe rot13(PNZRY) ?

Comment: where does 101 come from for 3?

Comment: @Jordan.J.D I clarified in the answer. It's from the vertical borders on the side and the circular border in the middle.

Comment: ER stands for Elizabeth Regina - which is basically latin for Queen Elizabeth.

Comment: @DrXorile interesting, the original stamp actually has '20' on it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A._Alisaffi. I think the answer uses twenty and the maker's name but I can't figure it out.

Comment: @DrXorile, Thank you for explaining. Why is Hermes Vet?

Comment: That's why I'm not happy with it. But I think Hermes is the god of shepherds and has that medical symbol with the snakes and dagger associated with him. But it's a bit of a stretch. So Vet for veterinarian, rather than veteran.

Comment: Ingenious solution for third stamp. My question for this had little rebusiousness and was more (bad) wordplay on a close relative of the person you identified. I can add my intended solution later (but it will likely disappoint). Also excellent answer to this puzzle.

Comment: Yes - that's the third one I was trying to clue (and I was concerned it was 
 too light). Wonderful!

Comment: Glad I got to it! The close relative got me on the right track.

Answer (score 5):

> Monarch butterfly
>
>  Helvetia butterfly
>
>  On the 3rd image we have Hermes, the Greek god and there is a Hermes copper butterfly but unfortunately I can't get to the equal length words.
>
>  So it must be butterflies as @Kit-Ginevra already suggested.

Comment: Helvetia butterfly is a new one for me, but the 3 rebuses answers are each composed of 2 or 3 sub-components from the image.

Answer (score 4):

3.

> Mercury inside a circle = Hg + O = Hog (swine)?

Comment: I was trying something like this, but it needs 5 letters to fit. Good ideas though.

Answer (score 4):

This might be a kind of silly answer for three, but...

> It's Hermes, on a stamp so.... Her + on = Heron?
>
>   Probably a stretch, but hey it's a 5-letter animal.

Comment: Decent answer and I'm afraid the third rebus is not as black and white as it should have been.

Answer (score 3):

> The first would be a monarch. I'm guessing the others are some variety of butterfly?

Comment: Good point, but in that case the kingdom would be rot13(Navznyvn).

Answer (score 3):

3. > [hermes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A._Alisaffi) Greek stamp, which is also a [butterfly](http://www.biologicaldiversity.org/species/invertebrates/Hermes_copper_butterfly/index.html). following @Dr Xorile method of answering, that stamp has a '20' at the bottom. So some amount of TWENTY in the animal's name... The stamp dealer that made the stamp in the picture is from Istanbul, ISO code from turkey is TR or TUR.

Comment: There's a butterfly effect happening, but you got a relevant name for the third image which I think has the least clear answer and I may be criticized for the relatively short cluing.

Answer (score 3):

Since this asking the kingdom, perhaps the kingdom is

> Animalia?

Observations:

> The first stamp is a picture of Queen Elizabeth = Britain.
>  The second stamp has the word Helvetia, which is some kind of spider or a female personification of Switzerland = Switzerland.
>  The last stamp seems to be a picture of Hermes = Greece